# Add JumpList customized category with check box

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, jump-list

Basically, I want to add a JumpTask into the Jump List context menu that allows the user to toggle the TopMost property.

Essentially I just want an entry that has a check box to turn the TopMost property on and off.

How do I do this? It would be nice if the Jump Task could just be a stack panel of a CheckBox and a TextBlock, then I could just bind directly to those. However, the properties on a Jump Task are very limiting, and I was wondering if anyone's figured out a good practice to have a checkbox + text show up in a jumplist

Comment: That sounds nice. What is your question?

Comment: How do I do this? It would be nice if the Jump Task could just be a stack panel of a CheckBox and a TextBlock, then I could just bind directly to those. However, the properties on a Jump Task are very limiting, and I was wondering if anyone's figured out a good practice to have a checkbox + text show up in a jumplist.

Comment: [What are the things you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This is the example I was looking at: http://www.wpftutorial.net/Jumplists.html
I could create a checkbox icon and toggle on its visibility, but that seems silly. Is there no way to just create my own control template for a JumpList item? As far as I can tell, the answer is no. But I'm asking to see if anyone has a better solution to this.

Comment: I guess a Jump list is only for opening files or applications. Doesn't seem like I can just add an entry that would modify a property in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this as the answer:
[Making a WPF system context menu item toggleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144154/making-a-wpf-system-context-menu-item-toggleable)

Considering the application I run is in XP, this is perfect for me. In the case I'm running on Vista or Windows 7, I added a MAIN context menu to my application where the user can change the TopMost property.